# Why won't all my functions execute, just the first one?

Tags: python

I'm learning to code and I got this task to create a program. (It is from Starting out with Python, 4th edition, Chapter 8, Exercise 14.)
I have created all functions and called them all yet the program will only execute one and return none for the rest. What am I missing?

```
def main():
   gas_file=open('GasPrices.txt', 'r')
   average_per_year(gas_file)
   print()
   average_per_month(gas_file)
   print()
   highest_lowers(gas_file)
   print()
   lowest_to_highest(gas_file)
   print()
   highest_to_lowest(gas_file)
   gas_file.close()
```

Here is full code: https://pastecode.xyz/view/b007ccb0
I get no error warning or anything btw

Kind regards, Juls

Answer (score 3):

The first function you call reads to the end of `gas_file` until it's at the end.  Since you pass the same file handle to all the other functions, they just see an empty file.

Your code would work (and be a lot simpler and faster than what you're trying to do) if instead of copying+pasting the code for reading the file into all of these functions, so that each is trying to re-read the file and do the same work repeatedly, you had a single function that parses the file into some useful data structure (like a list or a dict of values), and then had all the other functions just read the data from that.

Something like:

```
from typing import List, NamedTuple


class GasPrice(NamedTuple):
    month: int
    year: int
    price: float


def read_prices(gas_file: str) -> List[GasPrice]:
    """Load a list of GasPrices from a file."""
    with open(gas_file, 'r') as f:
        return [
            GasPrice(
                int(line[:2]),    # month
                int(line[6:10]),  # year
                float(line[11:])  # price
            )
            for line in f
        ]

def main() -> None:
    prices = read_prices('GasPrices.txt')
    # ... do stuff with prices
```